# How to dynamically modify database request in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, request

I've got a problem with my code. I need to get an instance of a model that looks like this:

```
class Example(models.Model):
    # ...
    foo = models.JSONField(default={})
```

and depending on the user's input (JSON key). For example:

```
Example.objects.filter(foo__userinput = bar)
```

How can I manage to don't make JSON key hardcoded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try filter by dict

```
key = 'foo__%s' % userinput
qfilter = {key: bar}
Example.objects.filter(**qfilter)
```